# How to make a cycle with a list in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, list, razor

In my asp mvc 3 application, I want to display an album of photos. So there will the selected picture and a list of thumbnails of the other pictures in the album. The list of thumbnails that the user will be able to see contains only 8 pictures, and all the others will be hidden. What I want is to start this list from the selected item and when the list reaches the end without finishing all the items it will restart from the beginning.

I managed to do it with this code, but I find it quick and dirty. Is there any built-in C# function I can use to do it ?

```
@{int i = 0;}
@foreach (AlbumPhoto albmphoto in Model.AlbumPhotoList
  .Where(p => p.AlbumPhotoId > int.Parse(SinglePhoto))
  .OrderBy(p => p.AlbumPhotoId))
{
    i++;
    string show = "none";
    if (i < 8)
    {
        show = "block";
    }
    <a href="#" style="display: @show">
        <img src="@Url.Content(albmphoto.AlbumPhotoPath)" width="70" height="47" border="0" alt="@albmphoto.AlbumPhotoDescription" />
    </a>                   
}

@foreach (AlbumPhoto albmphoto in Model.AlbumPhotoList
  .Where(p => p.AlbumPhotoId < int.Parse(SinglePhoto))
  .OrderBy(p => p.AlbumPhotoId))
{
    i++;
    string show = "none";
    if (i < 8)
    {
        show = "block";
    }
    <a href="#" style="display: @show">
        <img src="@Url.Content(albmphoto.AlbumPhotoPath)" width="70" height="47" border="0" alt="@albmphoto.AlbumPhotoDescription" />
    </a>                   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's anything built in to do a "rollover `foreach`" over an `IEnumerable`, but you could solve it slightly less disgustingly with a Concat, essentially appending the set of objects again to itself.

```
var photos = Model.AlbumPhotoList
  .Where(p => p.AlbumPhotoId < int.Parse(SinglePhoto))
  .OrderBy(p => p.AlbumPhotoId);

@foreach(var albumphoto in photos.Concat(photos))
{
  i++;
      string show = "none";
      if (i < 8)
      {
          show = "block";
      }
      <a href="#" style="display: @show">
          <img src="@Url.Content(albmphoto.AlbumPhotoPath)" width="70" height="47" border="0" alt="@albmphoto.AlbumPhotoDescription" />
      </a>       
}
```

And then it will roll over into the next set if it walks off the end.

Alternatively, as a better solution, you could ToList the IEnumerable and use a `%` to do better indexing:

```
var photos = Model.AlbumPhotoList
      .Where(p => p.AlbumPhotoId < int.Parse(SinglePhoto))
      .OrderBy(p => p.AlbumPhotoId)
      .ToList();

@for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
{
 if(i < 8)
 {
  show = "block";
 }
 var albumphoto = photos[i % photos.Count];
 <a href="#" style="display: @show">
  <img src="@Url.Content(albmphoto.AlbumPhotoPath)" width="70" height="47" border="0" alt="@albmphoto.AlbumPhotoDescription" />
 </a> 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did it with something like your first code but used a union instead. I split the list into 2 lists : the first one contains elements which come after the starting index and the other list contains the rest of the elements. And in the foreach loop I use : foreach(var albumphoto in photosAfter.Union(photosBefore))

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the value of `display` you could just leave the loop once you've got 8 entries (`break;`).

I haven't used asp.net/Linq yet (trying to get into it), but I'd try to do something like this (therefore consider it pseudo code; I'm open to feedback if this is complete BS or whatever!):

```
@{
    var index = int.Parse(SinglePhoto); // starting index
    var list = Model.AlbumPhotoList.OrderBy(...); // get all images
    // Now duplicate the first 8 elements of the list, then skip the images not visible
    // and then limit the number of visible items to 8
    list = list.Union(list.Top(8)).Skip(index).Top(8).ToList();
}
@foreach(AlbumPhoto photo in list){
    // html output
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, actually I want the pictures to be in my view and to be hidden.

Comment: Ah, ok. Will this essentially generate JavaScript to toggle it or will it use "static" HTML? Latter case this seems to be added overhead you wouldn't need in your HTML.